# How to write in spring application log?

Tags: java, spring, logging, tomcat7

My application is currently writing the following lines in Tomcat's `localhost.log` file.

```
Jan 09, 2017 4:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'reportDispatcher' 
Jan 09, 2017 4:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I want to dump these in `application.log`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Post your logging configuration file and the code you are using to log with.

Comment: Where do you define you application.log?

Comment: I define in log4j.xml under java resources.